# Turning off ConfigurationItems

Tags: astropy

I am doing some calculations involving propagation of uncertainties, and I keep getting a lot of useless information logs about correlated uncertainties being unsupported. I already know that, I don't care, and I would like to stop it printing these messages.

According to the documentation, it can "be disabled via the
        `WARN_UNSUPPORTED_CORRELATED` configuration item"

I can't figure out how to do that. How can I stop printing these unhelpful messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/index.html.

From there you can disable in your `astropy.cfg`:

```
[nddata]

## Whether to issue a warning if NDData arithmetic is performed with
## uncertainties and the uncertainties do not support the propagation of
## correlated uncertainties.
warn_unsupported_correlated = False
```

Or by code:

```
>>> import astropy.nddata
>>> astropy.nddata.conf.warn_unsupported_correlated = False
```